# jquery not firing in first click using delegate

Tags: jquery

I want to know that this example fires on second click not at first click, why? i am using delegate function. the example is http://jsfiddle.net/3avaG/.

I need this solution badly.

Thank you.

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/toggle-normal-no-longer-shows-hides-element

Comment: if first time you hide element show to how next time check [this edit](http://jsfiddle.net/3avaG/2/)

Comment: thanks, but toggle function initialize in separate, not actually work for my job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate has been depreciated and therefore won't work with jQuery 1.8. Change the version in your JSFiddle to 1.5 for example and it's fine.

**From the docs:**

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.
>   For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to
>   use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation
>   is in the .on() method.

**UPDATE:**

```
$('body').delegate('#as', 'click', function(e){
    $(this).toggle(function() {
        alert("First");
    }, function() {
        alert("Second");
    });
});
```

Comment: doing same on jQuery 1.4.4 even use on() method

Comment: Can you set an example up for that?

Comment: Yes, i have a link in my question, i change the jquery version in jsFiddle. Actually delegate event handler fire first but not shows the alert message in toggle() function, second click and then after always shows the toggle alert message. I want at vary first click it execute the toggle method. Because this <a></a> tag was append when another event occurs.

Comment: If there are another process that doing the same as toggle method, please gives me a suggestion. I want like that, first click do something....second click do another (the selector append by another event when successfully occur). Thanks

Comment: Ah right, so on toggle you want one thing to happen on one click and one to happen on the other? Is that right?

Comment: But this update does not work, because this tag i append by append() method, should i use delegate or bind this append tag. Without delegate event does not fire. thanks.

Comment: man, this is same as my link in question. the alert message first shows after second click...thanks

Comment: Ok please set up a Fiddle that explains why it doesn't work. It does one alert on one toggle and one on the other as discussed. I'm confused as to what you want / need.

Comment: After second click it shows the 'First' message, not in first click, i use your update code in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/MTSyW/  thanks

Comment: So you want it to show first on the first click, second on the second click and then what?

Comment: suppose i have a empty list. when a user click this selector add an apple in this list, after that, user again click this selector remove this particular apple from list. i know toggle method can do this, but need to use delegate() method (cause i mention before). But in this code, user click at very first time nothing added in list, that's weird, my question is how i solve it sir. thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for nice collaboration. All your answer and discussion help me getting update.

Comment: if i want to append list into another div, then again does the same (very first click do not append), ex: http://jsfiddle.net/SDz4H/  But i think that, i am doing something that works at very first click and so on, if i am doing right please cheer me up or wrong suggest me as always. link is- http://jsfiddle.net/r5HVM/   Thank you very much.